# Codeigniter Upload File not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

```
function submit_article() {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p style="color:red">', '<br/></p>');

    $my_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]|xss_clean'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'additionalUpload',
            'label' => 'Additional Upload',
            'rules' => 'callback_is_image'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($my_rules);

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //ERROR
        $data['title'] = ucfirst('submit Article');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('submit_article', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    } else {
        //SUCCESS
        $data['title'] = ucfirst('article Submitted');
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('forms_view/submit_article_success', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}

function is_image($value) {

    $config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|tiff';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_image', $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:red">', '<br/></p>'));
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        $this->upload->data();
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Hi every one, this is my controller function code for processing multipart form data in codeigniter, actually the field additionalUpload is not a required feild, but I want it to be validated if the user upload file in additionalUpload field of file type, when I run the above code and click on submit button without selecting any file its shows me error "You did not select a file to upload." which I do not want because this is not a required field, this is my first problem..

and second one is that when I select a file and click on submit button it again show me that "You did not select a file to upload.".

Note: I have just shown two fields of my form here that is title,additionalUpload but I have all total 9 fields.

THANKS IN ADVANCE PLEASE HELP ANYONE.

Comment: `$this->upload->do_upload('your_field_name')`

Comment: Thanks its work for me....this solve my second problem..but my first problem is still not solved..please help me @dianuj sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you have to put the name of the file field.

```
<input type="file" name="image"/>
$this->upload->do_upload('image');
```

Second, you can not have the max_width and max height 0

```
$config['max_width']    = '2048';
$config['max_height']   = '2048';
```

Try that first and then see

For validate field file:

```
if($_FILES['you_field_name']['tmp_name']){

       //your code  
}
```

A greeting

Comment: Thank you for your important time.. but we can have widht and height to 0 for unlimitedness.. now my problem is that this field not required this is an addtional field as name suggest.. so it should not show any error message when users had not selected any file.. but in my case it is showing the error i dont want this..any suggestion from your side?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one check if `$_FILES` is not empty then do the validation else do nothing

```
 $my_rules = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'rules' => 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[20]|xss_clean'
        )
    );

if(!empty($_FILES)){

     $my_rules[]= array(
            'field' => 'additionalUpload',
            'label' => 'Additional Upload',
            'rules' => 'callback_is_image'
        )
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules($my_rules);
```

In your upload function you need to specify the field name

```
$this->upload->do_upload('your_field_name')
```